# How many subdomains can you have on the intranet v internet

Tags: dns, subdomain

Apologies as this is a developer asking questions about networking

Internally we use names such as

myname.subdomain.domain.co.uk

Apparently this is because we using a forest(?). My question is, is this a name that can be accessed via the internet as well as the intranet

If this is in the wrong category please change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes

https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/65581/how-can-i-add-sub1-sub2-domain-com-to-my-godaddy-hosting-account

"So, if the server that is going to host your sub sub domain has IP 1.2.3.4, your DNS records should be like this :

```
sub2.sub1.domain.com.       A     1.2.3.4
www.sub2.sub1.domain.com.   A     1.2.3.4
```

If you want to use CNAME records :

```
sub2.sub1.domain.com.       A       1.2.3.4
www.sub2.sub1.domain.com.   CNAME   sub2.sub1.domain.com."
```